# Не выводятся данные из БД на форму в PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Здравстуйте, делаю редактирование данных в форме на php. Редактирование - работает, но нужно, чтобы данные, которые уже внесены в БД при создании отображались в окнах формы, но только получаю следующую ошибку заместо данных из БД:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: result in <b>C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
```

Скриншоты ошибки, структуру БД и код файла прилагаю.

[image: Ошибка в выводе данных]
[image: Структура БД]

Сам сайт находится на OpenServer. Форма редактирования edit_user.php

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
require_once "./components/header.php";
    
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'irsa';
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ( !$connect )
die("Проблема с соединением: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    // Проверка на заполненные данные
    if ( isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['login']) and isset($_POST['password'])and isset($_POST['phone']) ) {
    
      if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '{$_POST['username']}',`login` = '{$_POST['login']}',`password` = '{$_POST['password']}',`phone` = '{$_POST['phone']}' WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");
    } else {
        //Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `login`, `password`, `phone`) VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}', '{$_POST['login']}', '{$_POST['password']}', '{$_POST['phone']}')");
    }
      if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $sql = mysqli_fetch_array($connect, "SELECT `ID`, `username`, `login`, `password`, `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
      }
      header('Location: user_list.php');
    }
    ?>
<div class="container center center-vertical d-flex align-content-center">
    <form action="" class="form" method="POST">
        <legend>Обновление данных</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="<? isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['username'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['login'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['password'] : ''; ?>" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="phone" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['phone'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="margin-40 btn btn-danger" value="Обновить данные">
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    // Подключение подвала сайта
    require("components/footer.php")
?>
```

Comment: 'header('Location: user_list.php');' этот редирект уберите

Comment: @InDevX Редирект убрал, теперь сообщения предупреждения следующие, при нажатии обновить, но при загрузке самой формы ошибки так и остаюстя в полях, а нужны значения из БД. То есть понятно, что он не может взять данные из БД запросом и поэтому не вставляет их в форму. Но как исправить - не понимаю... `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php on line 24`

Comment: читаем ошибку - `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given`, переводим - функция mysqli_fetch_array ожидает что параметр 1 будет mysqli_result, а мы передаём объект. Смотрим код - `mysqli_fetch_array($sql)`, переменная $sql на ряд выше, и в ней уже хранится результат mysqli_fetch_array, то есть, вы аргументом функции mysqli_fetch_array передаёте результат выполнения функции mysqli_fetch_array, а она ожидает там результат выполнения mysqli_query. А первая `$sql = mysqli_fetch_array...` то же самое, ожидает результат выполнения функции mysqli_result

Comment: @InDevX То есть `$result` повторяет `$sql` и является бессмысленной и ее можно убрать, заменив в саомй форме на вывод `$sql`? И как тогда передать `mysqli_result` или `mysqli_query`? Потому что не совсем понятно...

Comment: Нет. Смотрите, у Вас повторяется условие `if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {`, второе - надо вынести до проверки - `// Проверка на заполненные данные` и `$sql = mysqli_fetch_array(...` заменить на `$sql = mysqli_result(...`, тогда переменная $result будет содержать запись, если есть в ссылке user_id. Потом, второе условие (проверка юзернейма, логина и пр.) содержит условие, что определяет запись на апдейт или добавление, и останется добавить выполнение запроса. А дальше уже логика Ваша, можно теперь редирект вернуть, чтобы после апдейте/добавление возвращались в файл user_list.php

Comment: @InDevX Изменения сделал, теперь ругается на вынесенную строчку `$sql = mysqli_result($connect, "SELECT `ID`, `username`, `login`, `password`, `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");` Ошибка следующая: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\irsa\edit_user.php on line 14`

Comment: @InDevX Все получилось, большое спасибо. Сделал следующим образом `if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `ID`, `username`, `login`, `password`, `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментариям @InDevX все получилось. Код, если кому-то нужен - прилагаю

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
require_once "./components/header.php";
    
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'irsa';
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ( !$connect )
die("Проблема с соединением: " . mysqli_connect_error());

if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `ID`, `username`, `login`, `password`, `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}

    // Проверка на заполненные данные
    if ( isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['login']) and isset($_POST['password'])and isset($_POST['phone']) ) {
    
      if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '{$_POST['username']}',`login` = '{$_POST['login']}',`password` = '{$_POST['password']}',`phone` = '{$_POST['phone']}' WHERE `ID`={$_GET['user_id']}");
    } else {
        //Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `login`, `password`, `phone`) VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}', '{$_POST['login']}', '{$_POST['password']}', '{$_POST['phone']}')");
    }

    header('Location: user_list.php');
    }
    ?>

<div class="container center center-vertical d-flex align-content-center">
    <form action="" class="form" method="POST">
        <legend>Обновление данных</legend>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['username'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['login'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['password'] : ''; ?>" >
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="phone" value="<?= isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $result['phone'] : ''; ?>">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="margin-40 btn btn-danger" value="Обновить данные">
      </div>

    </form>
</div>
<?php
    // Подключение подвала сайта
    require_once "./components/footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Только нельзя прям с формы данные в запросы вставлять, надо их валидировать, убирать спецсимволы, приводить к int где возможно и т.п..